# Translate phrases and words in a code automatically

Tags: translation, pawn

Is there a way to translate phrases and words in a script (pawn code) automatically without messing up the script, the script contains a lot of Russian it's hard to go through each word/phrase to translate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are working in SA-MP, there is a [plugin](https://github.com/IllidanS4/Pawn-DeepL) allowing to interface with the [DeepL](https://www.deepl.com/) API, allowing for translation of messages at runtime. You can hook `SendClientMessage` and similar functions to first translate the message, if needed.